# jQuery originalevent offsetx property?

Tags: jquery

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $o, os;

                //generate toolbar
                var $toolbar = $(".toolbar");
                $.each(tools, function (i, tool) {
                    $("<img>", tool).appendTo($toolbar);
                });
                var $tools = $toolbar.find("img");

                //define drag and drop handlers
                $toolbar.on("dragstart", "img", onDrag);
                $(".canvas").on({
                    dragenter: false,
                    dragover: false,
                    drop: onDrop
                });

                //handle commencement of drag
                function onDrag(e) {
                    $o = $(this).clone();
                    var o = e.originalEvent;
                    o.effectAllowed = "copy";
                    os = { X: o.offsetX, Y: o.offsetY };
                }

                //handle drop
                function onDrop(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var o = e.originalEvent;
                    var pos = { left: o.offsetX - os.X, top: o.offsetY - os.Y };
                    $o.css(pos);
                    $(this).append($o);
                    //***DATABASE example:-
                    // (1) Create dataset, e.g. JSON:-
                    var data = {
                        id: $o.data("id"),
                        description: $o.data("description"),
                        position: pos
                    };
                    // (2) Send (JSON) data to SQL webservice using AJAX POST:-   
                    //$.post("sqlwebservice.ashx", data);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            //define toolset (JSON, e.g. from database)...
            var tools = [{
                "data-id": 1,
                alt: "sun",
                title: "sun",
                src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png",
                "data-description": "sun in photo"
            }, {
                "data-id": 2,
                alt: "snow",
                title: "snow",
                src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Thermometer_Snowflake.png",
                "data-description": "snow in photo"
            }, {
                "data-id": 3,
                alt: "cloud",
                title: "cloud",
                src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Overcast.png",
                "data-description": "cloud in photo"
            }, {
                "data-id": 4,
                alt: "rain",
                title: "rain",
                src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Night_Rain.png",
                "data-description": "rain in photo"
            }];
```

This script works fine in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alano/E8rrX/. When I take it to my local machine the offsetx and offsety property of the original event is coming up as undefined. I had to change to clientx and clienty however those do not work in the correct way. Does anyone know why offsetx and offsety are coming as undefined when I run on my compuyter but not in fiddle?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pageX` and `pageY` It works in **firefox** . Hope it works on your `localhost`

Comment: I see yes there is a pagex. I'm curious now what happened to offsetx?